# Pandas - stack and rename columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have constructed a dataframe below (df2) where some column names have a suffix in the form #/#. The first number in these suffixes will match the number suffix in the corresponding "A" column:

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame( { 'A': ['X', 'X1', 'X1', 'X2', 'X2', 'X2', 'X2', 'X3', 'X3' ],
                     'Property': [ 'p', 'p', 'p1/1', 'p', 'p2/1', 'p2/2', 'p2/3', 'p3/1', 'p3/2' ],
                     'Value': [ 'u', 'v', 'a', 't', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b' ] } ) 

print df1

    A Property Value
0   X        p     u
1  X1        p     v
2  X1     p1/1     a
3  X2        p     t
4  X2     p2/1     a
5  X2     p2/2     b
6  X2     p2/3     c
7  X3     p3/1     a
8  X3     p3/2     b

indices = [ col for col in df1.columns.tolist() if col != 'Value' ]
df2 = df1.set_index( indices )[ 'Value' ].unstack( 'Property' ).reset_index().fillna('-')
print df2

    A  p  p1/1  p2/1  p2/2  p2/3  p3/1  p3/2
0   X  u  -     -     -     -     -     -
1   X1 v  a     -     -     -     -     -
2   X2 t  -     a     b     c     -     -
3   X3 -  -     -     -     -     a     b
```

How can I use stack (or some other method) on df2 to achieve a dataframe like below, where I condense some of the information by adding a new column x to identify the first number in the #/# suffix from the original dataframe?

```
    A  p  px/1  px/2  px/3  x
0   X  u  -     -     -     -
1   X1 v  a     -     -     1
2   X2 t  a     b     c     2
3   X3 -  a     b     -     3
```

Note, if there is a way to accomplish this directly from df1, that would be optimal for my situation, however modifying df2 may be more of a common use case for others.

Comment: Do you mind to share your df with `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: I have added some code/ updated question to generate the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it from the beginning

```
df1.Property=('px/'+df1.Property.str.split('/',expand=True)[1]).fillna(df1.Property)
df2 = df1.set_index( indices )[ 'Value' ].unstack( 'Property' ).reset_index()
df2
Out[1360]: 
Property   A     p  px/1  px/2  px/3
0          X     u  None  None  None
1         X1     v     a  None  None
2         X2     t     a     b     c
3         X3  None     a     b  None
```

Comment: This should be the way to go, I didn't even look at df1 :)

Comment: @bwrabbit yw/~ :-) happy coding

Answer (score 3):

This has to be the most obnoxious thing I've ever written

```
(
    df.set_index(['A', 'p'])
      .filter(regex='p\d+/\d+')
      .mask(lambda d: d == '-', '')
      .groupby(lambda x: x.split('/')[1], axis=1, )
      .sum()
      .mask(lambda d: d == '', '-')
      .add_prefix('px/')
      .reset_index()
      .assign(x=lambda d: d.A.str.extract('(\d+)$', expand=False).fillna('-'))
)

    A  p px/1 px/2 px/3  x
0   X  u    -    -    -  -
1  X1  v    a    -    -  1
2  X2  t    a    b    c  2
3  X3  -    a    b    -  3
```

Comment: Something to bring smile on a boring day :)

Answer (score 2):

First create column x then groupby axis 1 and sum strings

```
df.replace('-', '', inplace = True)
df['x'] = df.A.str.extract('(\d)', expand = False)
df = df.groupby(df.columns.str[-1], axis =1 ).sum().replace('', '-')
df.rename({'1' : 'px/1', '2' : 'px/2', '3' : 'px/3'}, axis = 1, inplace = True)

    px/1    px/2    px/3    A   p   x
0   -       -       -       X   u   0.0
1   a       -       -       X1  v   1.0
2   a       b       c       X2  t   2.0
3   a       b       -       X3  -   3.0
```